# Beamer 2-up with projected frame above and notes below

Tags: beamer, notes

How can I create a printout of my beamer slides 2-up, with the displayed frame on the top half, and the following `\note{}` frame on the bottom half of the page?  If there is no `\note{}` page, the bottom half should be blank. If I do `\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}`, pages without notes remove the alignment on a single page between a frame and the corresponding note.  [This](http://www.guidodiepen.nl/2009/07/creating-latex-beamer-handouts-with-notes/) is exactly what I want, except I'm not handwriting my notes on lines, I'm using `\note`s.  Judging by the comments on that blog, I'm not the only one who'd like this feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work, without using the other .sty file. It's arguably an abuse of how you'd keep a second screen of notes while you were giving your presentation, but it works and is very simple.

[image]

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm] % could also use letterpaper
\setbeamertemplate{note page}[plain] % Beamer manual, section 19.1
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=bottom} % Beamer manual, section 19.3

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Here's some content, with no notes added.
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
Here's some content, with notes added.
\end{frame}
\note{
Here are things to remember:
\begin{enumerate}
\item Stress this first.
\item Then this.
\end{enumerate}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I like this; very simple.  I understand it's a mild misuse of "second screen" but I would use it for printouts only.  I have a shell script anyway that injects the pgfpageuselayout temporarily to make the hardcopy form, so this is not much harder to add.

Comment: Is there also a solution which produces A4 paper with 16:9 Slides? 
Unfortunately the result is not A4 :-)

Comment: Apparently, the original 4:3 version of this wasn't quite A4, either. Ratio of 1.5 instead of sqrt(2). Adding `aspectratio=169` to the class options gives a ratio of 1.12.