# beamer note spacing issue

Tags: beamer, line-spacing, notes

I’m having a problem with beamer, where the first paragraph in a note has different spacing from subsequent ones.

MWE:

```
\AtBeginDocument{\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=left}}

\documentclass[17pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeamertemplate{note page}{\insertnote}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}
Content
\end{frame}

\note{Hello everyone, and welcome to my talk. Today I'll be presenting
about Title.}

\begin{frame}{Introduction}
Content
\end{frame}

\note{Title first came to prominence in 1883 when Author first described
the phenomenon.

There has since been a great deal of subsequent research on it.}

\end{document}
```

comes out as

[image]

The first paragraph is single-spaced, but the next one is double-spaced.

Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the first answer to [Displaying slides with Beamer and Article class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38084/displaying-slides-with-beamer-and-article-class), this seems to be a known bug. The solution that andrew provides does fix the problem, but then you won't get a tiny image of the slide included on the notes page. The fix I use, which does include an image of the slide, is to add an extra empty paragraph like this:

```
\note{Title first came to prominence in 1883 when Author first described
the phenomenon.

There has since been a great deal of subsequent research on it.

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix it by changing the template to

```
\setbeamertemplate{note page}{\insertnote\par}
```