# pdflatex "Required Page Does Not Exist" error with beamerarticle

Tags: beamer, errors, pdftex, input, beamerarticle

I have several `beamer` tex files and need to create a manual (using beamerarticle) that incorporates all of the beamer files (with their notes) as one document. The original basis of the articlebeamer output can be found here: [Displaying slides with Beamer and Article class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38084/displaying-slides-with-beamer-and-article-class)

Right now I have the following:

- `chapter1.tex`
- `chapter2.tex`
- `chapter1.beamer.tex`
- `chapter2.beamer.tex`
- `full.article.tex`

`full.article.tex` has something like this:

```
% BEGIN FULL.ARTICLE.TEX
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\usepackage{pgf}

\setjobnamebeamerversion{chapter1.beamer}
\setjobnamebeamerversion{chapter2.beamer}

\newcommand{\showslide}[1]{
    \begin{figure}
        \center \fbox{\includeslide[width=10cm]{#1}}
    \end{figure}
}

\input{chapter1.tex}
\input{chapter2.tex}
% END FULL.ARTICLE.TEX
```

I already ran `pdflatex` on the `*.beamer.tex` files so the corresponding PDF outputs are in the same folder as the `full.article.tex`.

Running `pdflatex full.article.tex`, I get the following error:

```
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file ./chapter2.beamer.pdf): PDF inclusion: required page does not exist <8>
```

Would appreciate any help in figuring out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you have already prepared `pdf` files you can use the following MWE to collect them to one `pdf` file (`full.article.tex`):

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{pdfpages} % http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages

\begin{document}
  \includepdf[pages=-]{chapter1.beamer.pdf}
  \includepdf[pages=-]{chapter2.beamer.pdf}
% \includepdf[pages=-]{chapter3.beamer.pdf}
\end{document}
```

With macro `\includepdf` you can include complete or pages of the named `pdf` file in your document. Document class `minimal` gives no margins so your included `pdf` files are unchanged.

Comment: I was thinking of that, but it would mean having to generate presentation (beamer) and handout (beamerarticle) PDF before being able to actually come up with a full "manual" based on the generated handouts. That's quite a lot of tex files to make. The other problem with this solution is that the page numbers restart for every new handout that's included in the resulting PDF. Would like to know if there's a much better solution out there.

Comment: Still a hassle. But I guess I'll have to go with that one until someone comes up with a much better solution.