# block environment without beamer

Tags: beamer, article, block, beamerarticle

I like the block environment, namely:

```
\begin{block}{Example}
Something interesting
\end{block}
```

However, it seems it is linked to beamer. So, is it possible to have something like the block environment when you have `\documentclass{article}`?

I added the package `\usepackage{beamerarticle}` which I found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38084/displaying-slides-with-beamer-and-article-class), but when I use `block` it doesn't really show the block.

Comment: The output of the `block` environment depends on the `beamer` theme you use, but if you're referring the the more colorful ones, you can achieve a similar output using the `tcolorbox` package in your article.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass[twocolumn,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings,shadows}



\newenvironment{gblock}[1]{%
\tcolorbox[beamer,%
noparskip,breakable,
colback=LightGreen,colframe=DarkGreen,%
colbacklower=LimeGreen!75!LightGreen,%
title=#1]}%
{\endtcolorbox}



\begin{document}

\begin{gblock}{Example of \texttt{exampleblock}}
wwwwwwwwwwwwww
\end{gblock}

\end{document}
```

**Or you may also like this**

```
 \begin{tcolorbox} 
 [colback=white!100,colframe=red!75!black,width=10cm, 
 righttitle=0.5cm,subtitle style={boxrule=0.4pt, 
 colback=yellow!50!red!25!white},title= \bf{qqqqqqqq}\hfill  
 \bf{qqqqqqqqqqq}]
    \begin{center}\bf{aaaaaaaaa}\end{center}
    \tcblower
    qqqqqqqqqqqqq
\end{tcolorbox}
```

[image]