# Inserting beamer slides into a regular document

Tags: beamer

To the presentation, I want to add a file with a speech plan to each of the slides. To do this, I can use the independent writing of each of the texts, which in practice is not a good approach, because it requires monitoring the relevance of the information in each of the documents. Another solution is to write one file with both slides and the text to them, and then, using two different preambles, implement the creation of both files. If there are no problems with the presentation, then I have difficulties with the document. How can I insert a presentation slide in the form of an image into a document if this slide is only in the form of the source text?

Perhaps my task can be solved in a different way, simpler. If so, please share your knowledge.

Comment: My answer shows the default aspect for `notes` but you can also look at [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38146/1952) where a new notes page format is defined. The question for this answer explains how to use `article` class with `beamerarticle` package and `includeslide` command to insert beamer slides inside an article document.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what you need. Your detailed answer is undoubtedly useful and conveys the main essence of the idea, but the more practical way is with a sheet of paper, rather than with an additional slide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `notes` to your beamer presentation and create a `notes` version of your document.

This is an example with the result:

```
\documentclass[notes]{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{This is the first frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item First item
\item Second item
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\note{This is what I want to say about this slide}
\end{document}
\end{document}
```

[image]