# Beamer "show notes on second screen" with pgfpages "4 on 1"

Tags: beamer, pgfpages

I'm trying to build on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36150/beamer-2-up-with-projected-frame-above-and-notes-below):

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm] % could also use letterpaper
\setbeamertemplate{note page}[plain] % Beamer manual, section 19.1
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=bottom} % Beamer manual, section 19.3

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Here's some content, with no notes added.
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
Here's some content, with notes added.
\end{frame}
\note{
Here are things to remember:
\begin{enumerate}
\item Stress this first.
\item Then this.
\end{enumerate}
}
\end{document}
```

I'd like to print two slides per page, but I can't get it to work:

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm] % could also use letterpaper
\setbeamertemplate{note page}[plain] % Beamer manual, section 19.1
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=bottom} % Beamer manual, section 19.3
%\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm]

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Here's some content, with no notes added.
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
Here's some content, with notes added.
\end{frame}
\note{
Here are things to remember:
\begin{enumerate}
\item Stress this first.
\item Then this.
\end{enumerate}
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can print 4 on 1 if you use `\setbeameroption{show notes}` for the handout mode.

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\usepackage{pgfpages}

\mode<handout>{%
    \pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=7mm]
    \setbeameroption{show notes}
}


\mode<beamer>{%
    \setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=bottom}
}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
1 Here's some content, with no notes added.
\note{test}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
2 Here's some content, with notes added.
\end{frame}
\note{
Here are things to remember:
\begin{enumerate}
\item Stress this first.
\item Then this.
\end{enumerate}
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: This cannot be done.

Long answer:

The `show notes on second screen` beamer option uses a `pgfpagesuselayout{two screens with optional second}` internally. If you then use `pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}`, you overrule the layout set prior. So it doesn't work anymore.

You might think that you could create a custom pgfpagesuselayout, and you would be right. It's not that hard to create a layout comparable to `two screens with optional second` but with four screens, so `four screens with optional second and fourth` or something like that.

But Beamer doesn't 'know' how to handle that custom layout properly. One of the issues I encountered is that Beamer will always paste it notes into the optional second 'screen', because it isn't aware of the fourth optional 'screen'. And it will always post a slide into the fourth screen, so it becomes a page like this:

```
 slide 1 | note 4  
---------|---------
 slide 3 | slide 4
```

So you can't get this to work without changing Beamer itself.

### Workarounds

I found these two workarounds to be helpful.

*Workaround 1: show only notes*

```
\setbeameroption{show only notes}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[border shrink=10pt]
```

You should not use `\setbeamertemplate{note page}[plain]` but just use the defaults. That way you get the note page with a small thumbnail of the slide.

[image: Show only notes]

Cons:

Slides without notes won't get printed. So you should post a note (even an empty one) on each slide.

*Workaround 2: print to pdf*

Use

```
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=bottom}
\setbeamertemplate{note page}[plain]
```

And print the resulting pdf using a pdf printer. Fiddle with the print dialog to get two (or more pages) on a page.
[image: Print Dialog]

Cons:

You have to do an extra operation

I like both workarounds better than samcarter's answer, because if you just use `show notes` with `4 on 1` you have no control over on which side the notes will appear.